# Retrofit 1.9 doesn't post data correctly to server side

Tags: android, retrofit

Hello i have a problem with post method on retrofit 1.9.

I'm sending a data in Pojo as a @Body and it's return that i didn't send anything.

Here is the code of serviceInterface :
    @POST(Constants.API_MAKE_ORDERS)
    void makeOffers(@Body MarketPlaceRequest marketPlaceRequest,
                    Callback callback);
[image]

[[image: [2]]

Thx in advance.

While debuging code,where you can see filled request
And here is a log of retrofit in android monitor]

Comment: Your server is probably case sensitive and your serialized fields are not capitalized

Comment: i did serialzedname on every field in object.

Comment: Well we can't see that can we?

Comment: sry didnt post,thought it doesn't matter when i know i need to serialzedName on every field,maybe some other idea?